# How to check whether an int is within a range of values

Tags: java, if-statement

In a particular `if-else`, I have to identify if a given value falls within a range. The condition part looks like this:

```
else if (a==2 && b.equalsIgnoreCase("line")
     && <<Here I need to search if c falls within a range>> && d)
```

where a is int, b is string, c is int and d is a boolean. Now if c falls within 1 to 8, the condition is true, else it is false. How can I do that?

Comment: Where you want to search c?

Comment: In the braced part of `else-if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need you this condition for `c`

```
(c > 1 && c < 8) // 1 and 8 are exclusive
(c => 1 && c <= 8) // 1 and 8 are inclusive
```

Full sample

```
else if (a==2 && b.equalsIgnoreCase("line")
     && (c > 1 && c < 8) && d)
```

If you need to check if the values belongs to a set of values, you need to use a `Set` and then check if the `c` belongs to that or not. In your original question, it was mentioned as **a range** and thus the answer. Anyways, this is how you can check a value in a set.

```
Integer[] arr = {1,4,9,11,13};
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
...
else if (a==2 && b.equalsIgnoreCase("line")
     && (set.contains(c)) && d)
```

Comment: And if the values are not sequential?

Comment: I don't quite understand, what you mean by that. Can you give a sample?

Comment: Suppose if I want to search if c falls within {1,4,9,11,13}, then?

Comment: @Mistu4u In that case, if I was using it more than once, I'd create a `HashSet<Integer>` (I'll call it `set`) and use `set.contains(c)`.

Comment: @Mistu4u Then that's not a range, it's a set, and you should use `Set`.

Comment: @Mistu4u Or, use a [switch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: Ah, okay. thank you all for your participation. I just added the part to make the question more wholesome. :)

Comment: ..And someone downvotes the answer without leaving a comment. Geez!

Answer (score 3):

Surprise surprise, it is `c >= low && c <= high`

To answer to the update, you'll need to employ a set

```
Set<Integer> validValues = new HashSet<Integer>();
validValues.add(1);
validValues.add(4);
validValues.add(9);
validValues.add(10);
validValues.add(19);

if (validValues.contains(currentVal)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

To curb java's verbosity you may use Guava's immutable set:

```
Set<Integer> validValues = ImmutableSet.of(1, 4, 9, 10, 19);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, range1 and range2 are ranges from which you need to check b.

```
(c < range1 && c >  range2) ? d=true : d=false;
```

Comment: You misinterpreted the question. The first part of your answer is correct. However, the OP didn't want a ternary expression, he wanted an `if` statement. Try re-reading the question.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add:

```
c > 1 && c < 8
```

If you ever feel that your conditionals are getting too complicated I'd suggest creating Boolean methods that simplify them down a little. This is a very moderate case, but for example this range problem could be represented by:

```
public boolean inRange(int num)
{
    return (num > 1 && num < 8);
}
```

Comment: Why `Boolean`? `boolean` will almost always suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only way to do it would be using if else statements (as far as I know). A switch statement does not accept conditional operators, and so would not work for that. As suggested by some others, you could use seperate methods, as the methods, would allow you to check if other values were in range as well. Instead of just for this value, however, you could go for something like

```
public Boolean inRange(int num, int lowBound, int topBound)
{
    return (num > lowBound && num < topBound);

}
```

and just use it in your code like this

```
else if (a==2 && b.equalsIgnoreCase("line")
     && inBound(c, 1, 8) && d)
```

It does not look too messy, and will work (you'll need to decide whether it is inclusive or exclusive bounds though).

The reason for the changed method is that it could be used in other places as well, making it useful for range checking.

Comment: I personally don't think that `(num > lowBound && num < topBound)` is messy. However, when I join many conditionals together in one statement, I almost always split lines. I'd use `else if (a == 2 \\new line``&& b.equalsIgnoreCase("line") \\nl``&& (c > 1 && c < 8) \\nl``&& d`

Comment: That is what i meant - not too messy. Anyway, split lines is good. Although, if the visual effect is what is what the person is going for, then you could just nest them as well - there isn't much of a performance change for that